# Showing that a linear map with given idempotent like property splits into direct sum of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, direct-sum

I am trying to solve the following question:

Suppose that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and that $\alpha : V → V$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map such that $\alpha^n = 1$ for some $n > 1$ . Show that if $V_1$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $\alpha(V_1) \subseteq V_1$ , then there is a subspace $V_2$ of $V$ such that $V = V_1 ⊕ V_2$ and $\alpha(V_2) \subseteq V_2$ .

[Hint: Show, for example by picking bases, that there is a linear map $π : V → V_1$ with
$π(x) = x$ for all $x ∈ V_1$. Then consider $ρ : V → V_1$ with $ρ(y) = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}α^iπα^{−i}(y)$.]

I think I have a solution but I am getting an uneasy feeling about my argument as it feels convoluted, can someone please verify:

Let $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k$ be a basis for $V_1$. Extend this to a basis for $V$ given by $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k,w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_l$. Then $\pi$ is the projection map which sends $v_i$ to itself and $w_j$ to $0$ (hence it exists). We now forget about the $w_i$ as they are only used to show the projection map exists.

Define $\rho$ as in the hint. Note that $\rho(\alpha(y)) = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^i\pi\alpha^{-i+1}(y) = \alpha(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^{i-1}\pi\alpha^{-(i-1)}(y))$. This is equal to $\alpha(\rho(y))$ as $\alpha^n = 1$ so $\alpha^{-1} = \alpha^{n-1}$. Hence $\alpha\circ \rho = \rho \circ \alpha$ so they commute.

We can also note that for any $a \in V_1$ as $\alpha(V_1) \subset V_1$ we have $\rho(a) = a$. So $\text{im } \rho = V_1$. We now apply the isomorphism theorem to $\rho$. We have $\frac{V}{\ker\rho} \cong \text{im } \rho$. Taking dimensions and rearranging we get $ \dim(V) = \dim(\ker \rho)+\dim(\text{im } \rho)$. So $\dim(\ker \rho) = \dim(V)-\dim(V_1) $.

So let $x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_l$ be a basis for $\ker \rho$. Then $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_l$ are all linearly independent (in V) as if $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k+b_1x_1+\cdots+b_lx_l = 0$ Then applying $\rho$ gives us $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k = 0$ so as $v_i$ are linearly independent we get $a_i = 0$ for all $i$ and as the $x_i$ are linearly independent we also get $b_i = 0$ for all $i$.

So $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_l$ is a linearly independent set the size of the dimension of $V$ so it is a basis. So $V_1 + \ker \rho = V$ and also $V_1 \cap \ker\rho = \{ 0\}$. So $V_1 \oplus \ker\rho = V$. Now note that if $x \in \ker \rho$ then $0 = \alpha(0) = \alpha(\rho(x)) = \rho(\alpha(x))$ so $\alpha(x) \in \ker \rho$. So $\alpha(\ker \rho) \subset \ker \rho$ and we are done by letting $V_2 = \ker \rho$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nice - it also looks fine to me.

FWIW you can avoid (some of ?) the explicit 'basis' type argument by setting $\sigma= 1 - \rho$, verifying that it is $\alpha$-linear, that $\sigma^2=\sigma$ since $\rho^2=\rho$, and, with $V_2= \sigma (V)$, that $V_2$ is stable under $\alpha$ and that $V_1 + V_2 = V$ is a direct sum decomposition of $V$.

FWIW (again!), this is a special case of Maschke's theorem.

Comment: BTW, this is (of course) a standard argument. But even if you are 'ok' with it, you should go with your version.

Comment: I haven't seen this sort of argument before, will definitely read up on Maschke's theorem.

Comment: Maschke's theorem is about groups acting on vector spaces (with certain hypotheses) - not really the 'idempotent' stuff here, which, really, might just be window dressing. But the proof of Maschke's th'm uses the same 'averaging' argument as in your hint. In fact, the same averaging works not only for finite groups, but for compact groups acting on a v.s, where the sum is replaced by an integral.